# Redirect single page to HTTP and the rest to HTTPS in Opencart

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I have installed opencart 1.5.6.4 and I need to redirect only one page 
    https://www.example.com/payment/ccavenuepay/callback to
    http://www.example.com/payment/ccavenuepay/callback . How do I achieve it using htaccess file.

My current htaccess as follows .

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

need to keep the redirection non www to www and http to https for all pages , and one page need to use http